# A javascript that can display a different image, every minute of the day

Tags: javascript, image, clock

I am very new at JavaScript. I am trying to do a javascript on a php page that can display one different photo from a folder every minute of the day. The folder contains 1440 images and are named accordingly so at 7:15 a file named 0715.jpg will be displayed.
So far, I have this code (mostly suggested by user Blzn) who suggested a better approach than the one I was using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var previousImg = null;

function updateImage() {

  var d = new Date();
  var h = d.getHours().toString();
  var m = d.getMinutes().toString();

  if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
  if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;

  var img = h + m + '.jpg';

  if (previousImg !== img) {
    var el = document.getElementById('image');
    el.src = '/img/' + img;
    previousImg = img;
  }
}
//updateImage(); // call the first time
setTimeout("updateImage()", 30000); // update each 20 seconds

//function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
//    var img = document.createElement('img');
//    img.src = '/img/' + img;
    img.width = 800;
    img.height = 400;
    img.alt = "Hello.";
//}
document.body.appendChild(img); 
window.onload=updateImage();
//}
</script>
</head>
```

I put this on the  element and is called by

```
<img id='image' src='img/img.jpg' />
```

that I put on the HTML body of the page.
As I sais, I'm very new at this and probably making a domb mistake. Please help!.

Comment: What is the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: I would use `setInterval("updateImage()", 1000)` instead of `setTimeout()` to have the action repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty simple!

Let's suppose we have an image in our html with the id `myImg`.

So, you call the `setInterval` function to change your image each 1min (setInterval expects a function that will be called and the time in ms).

The interval function must be called **after** the `<img>` tag is loaded in your html.

You can both put in a `DOMContentLoad`event or place the javascript code just after the tag in your html.

```html
<img id="myImg" alt="Some image" src="0000.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function() {
    var myImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
    myImg.src = new Date().toTimeString().substring(0, 5).replace(':', '') + '.jpg';
  }, 60000);
</script>
```

So, we take the current HHmm and replaces the image's `src` property.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your purpose, but I made out my necessary assumption.
The following code should work fine, it will append the image displayed every one minute, by assigning the right image.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
   <script type="text/javascript">

        function updateImage() {

          var d = new Date();
          var h = d.getHours().toString();
          var m = d.getMinutes().toString();

          if (h < 10) {h = '0' + h};
          if (m < 10) {m = '0' + m};

          var img = h + m + '.jpg';
          var el = document.getElementById('image');
          var src = 'img/' + img;
          el.setAttribute('src', src);

        }

        window.onload=function () {

            // we create a variable to hold a reference to the img element
            var img = document.getElementById('image');
            // we change the img properties (attributes) as requried
            img.width = 800;
            img.height = 400;
            img.alt = "Hello.";
            //updateImage();
            // we use the  setInterval method to call the updateImage() function every 60000millisceonds = 60 seconds = 1minute
            setInterval(updateImage(),60000);
        }
        //}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="image" src=""/>

</body>

</html>
```